# temporal go client, Client.CheckHealth() example

Tags: go, temporal-workflow

I am new to [temporal](https://temporal.io/), using the [Go SDK](https://github.com/temporalio/sdk-go). The [Client interface](https://github.com/temporalio/sdk-go/blob/7151653bdadc6d2645d3543bfc3ad5dfd3bd4551/client/client.go#L95) defines a **CheckHealth** [method](https://github.com/temporalio/sdk-go/blob/7151653bdadc6d2645d3543bfc3ad5dfd3bd4551/client/client.go#L381). Where can I find a simple example of its usage? I couldn't find anything inside the [samples](https://github.com/temporalio/samples-go#samples-directory).

I got the method to execute, but it returns nothing:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"

    "go.temporal.io/sdk/client"

    "github.com/temporalio/samples-go/helloworld"
)

func main() {
    log.Println("Starting")

    // The client is a heavyweight object that should be created once per process.
    c, err := client.Dial(client.Options{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Unable to create client", err)
    }
    log.Println("Client created", c)

    // Check client health
    checkHealthRequest := client.CheckHealthRequest{
    }

    checkHealthResponse, err := c.CheckHealth(context.Background(), &checkHealthRequest) 
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Unable to check health", err)
    }
    log.Println("checkHealthResponse", checkHealthResponse)

    defer c.Close()

    workflowOptions := client.StartWorkflowOptions{
        ID:        "hello_world_workflowID",
        TaskQueue: "hello-world",
    }

    we, err := c.ExecuteWorkflow(context.Background(), workflowOptions, helloworld.Workflow, "Temporal")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Unable to execute workflow", err)
    }

    log.Println("Started workflow", "WorkflowID", we.GetID(), "RunID", we.GetRunID())

    // Synchronously wait for the workflow completion.
    var result string
    err = we.Get(context.Background(), &result)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Unable get workflow result", err)
    }
    log.Println("Workflow result:", result)
}
```

Returns:

```
gitpod /workspace/samples-go (main) $ go run helloworld/starter/main_matt.go
2022/08/01 03:15:38 Starting
2022/08/01 03:15:38 INFO  No logger configured for temporal client. Created default one.
2022/08/01 03:15:38 Client created &{0xc0001a8950 0xc0002a7180 default 0xc0002aa3c0 0xc0001a4c18 {} 15492@temporalio-samplesgo-3fes2zok5o7@ 0xc0001fe460 [] [] 0xc0001a8958 0xc00019fc50 0xc0002b6860 {{0 0} 0 0 0 0}}
2022/08/01 03:15:38 checkHealthResponse &{}
2022/08/01 03:15:38 Started workflow WorkflowID hello_world_workflowID RunID 80727872-4df5-4fab-b96a-484276748e36
2022/08/01 03:15:38 Workflow result: Hello Temporal!
```

Comment: Based on the documentation, it looks like the method is called like this: `if _, err := client.CheckHealth(ctx, &client.CheckHealthRequest{}); err != nil { /* health is bad */} else { /* health is good */ }` where `ctx` is a [context.Context](https://pkg.go.dev/context#Context).

Comment: The documentation says "If the check fails, an error is returned."   The health is good if `err == nil`.

Answer (score 2):

Answer based on comments from **Cerise Limón** above

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"

    "go.temporal.io/sdk/client"

    "github.com/temporalio/samples-go/helloworld"
)

func main() {
    log.Println("Starting")

    // The client is a heavyweight object that should be created once per process.
    c, err := client.Dial(client.Options{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Unable to create client", err)
    }
    log.Println("Client created", c)

    // Check client health
    // The documentation says "If the check fails, an error is returned." The health is good if err == nil. 
    if _, err := c.CheckHealth(context.Background(), &client.CheckHealthRequest{}); err != nil {
        /* health is bad */
        log.Println("Health is bad")
    } else {
        /* health is good */
        log.Println("Health is good")
    }

    defer c.Close()

    workflowOptions := client.StartWorkflowOptions{
        ID:        "hello_world_workflowID",
        TaskQueue: "hello-world",
    }

    we, err := c.ExecuteWorkflow(context.Background(), workflowOptions, helloworld.Workflow, "Temporal")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Unable to execute workflow", err)
    }

    log.Println("Started workflow", "WorkflowID", we.GetID(), "RunID", we.GetRunID())

    // Synchronously wait for the workflow completion.
    var result string
    err = we.Get(context.Background(), &result)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Unable get workflow result", err)
    }
    log.Println("Workflow result:", result)
}
```

```
gitpod /workspace/samples-go (main) $ go run helloworld/starter/main_matt.go
2022/08/01 03:30:29 Starting
2022/08/01 03:30:29 INFO  No logger configured for temporal client. Created default one.
2022/08/01 03:30:29 Client created &{0xc00012e950 0xc000231180 default 0xc0002323c0 0xc00012ac18 {} 18770@temporalio-samplesgo-3fes2zok5o7@ 0xc00017e460 [] [] 0xc00012e958 0xc000125c50 0xc000038748 {{0 0} 0 0 0 0}}
2022/08/01 03:30:29 Health is good
2022/08/01 03:30:29 Started workflow WorkflowID hello_world_workflowID RunID 03cfd328-77c1-4d7a-9d5e-86d82e44c034
2022/08/01 03:30:29 Workflow result: Hello Temporal!
```